# How do you implement lazy token authentication for non-registered users in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, authentication, devise

*UPDATE*

*I have further clarified my question, listed at the end of this post.*

## Problem Summary:

I am trying to implement lazy (aka soft sign-up) registration in Devise via an emailed URL which includes token authentication.  On my site, a `User` `has_many :payments`, and a `Payment` `belongs_to :user`.  When a `User` creates a new `Payment`, it includes the attribute `:email` which represents a new non-registered user (which I'll call "Guest").  I use ActionMailer to send an email to this new Guest.

In this email that is sent, I would like to include a URL with token authentication (e.g. `http://localhost/index?auth_token=TOKENVALUE`), so that the Guest can see and edit views that require authentication and are specifically customized to them (based on their `:email`).  The Guest should also have the ability to register as a `User` - since I already have their email address, they would just need to provide a password.

## My Progress So Far:

- I have implemented the ability for someone to register for the site using Devise and created the associated views, model and controller to make changes to my `Payment` model
- I have setup ActionMailer and am using it to send emails, but have not yet setup token-authentication as I'm not sure how to do so given my use case above

## Related Resources:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example
- http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise
- [Multiple user models with Ruby On Rails and devise to have separate registration routes but one common login route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299618/multiple-user-models-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-to-have-seperate-registration)
- [how to create a guest user in Rails 3 + Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391883/how-to-create-a-guest-user-in-rails-3-devise)
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user
- http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1679-lazy-user-registration-for-rails-apps/
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record?view=asciicast
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface
- [Rails 3 - Devise Gem - How to Manage Users through CRUD interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721276/rails-3-devise-gem-how-to-manage-users-through-crud-interface)
- http://danielboggs.com/articles/rails-authentication-and-user-management-via-crud/

**/app/models/payment.rb**

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :description, :email, :frequency, :paid, :user_id
  belongs_to :user

  validates :email, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /.+@.+\..+/i }
  validates :amount, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
end
```

**/app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # I will also need to add ":token_authenticatable"

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :payments
end
```

## Questions:

1. How can I keep my `User` table in sync with new `Payments` that are created, such that any new `:email` created in the `Payment` table automatically are added in the `User` table as an `:email`?
2. Following from question 1, the new `User` created should include a token but not include a password, since the User has not yet registered for the site. Should I create the new `User` with a blank password, randomly generated string, or other?  In either case, I think they would need to come to the registration page from their token-authenticated URL to prevent others from registering under their email username (e.g. lazy registration)
3. Following from question 2, I think that I will need to distinguish between Guests and normal users, as some of the views will change depending on user type.  Is there a preferred method other than adding a column that would have a 0 or 1 to delineate between the two user types?

My preference if possible is to use Devise since I am using many of the features included.  I'm new to RoR and appreciate any advice you can provide!

*EDIT:  Here is the code I used to address question #1 above, in my payments controller, in case helpful to someone else*

```
def create
    @payment = current_user.payments.build(params[:payment])

    #Here is the code I added to keep User :email in sync with Payment :email, without token authentication implemented yet
    unless User.find_by_email(params[:payment][:email].downcase)  
      u = User.new({:email => params[:payment][:email].downcase, :password => nil, :password_confirmation => nil })
      u.skip_confirmation!
      u.save(:validate => false)  #skip validation
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.save
        format.html { redirect_to payments_url, :flash => { notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' } }
        format.json { render json: @payment, status: :created, location: @payment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frameworks like Devise are great when you know how to use them well and what you want to do fits within what the framework was designed to do. When you start trying to "bend" them to do things they weren't designed to do, though, perhaps trying to monkey-patch them without fully understanding how they work internally, in my experience, you just make a mess. I've been there. Often you are reduced to just "hacking until it works"... which really means "hacking until it appears to work, aside from a dozen subtle bugs which only show up later".

In a case like this, I would be inclined to just "roll my own" login and authentication code, perhaps looking at the Devise source code for ideas.

(In fact, I did just that today on a new Rails app... it took a couple hours of hours, checking the Devise source for ideas now and again, to write the 200 lines of code my project actually needed. Devise itself, in comparison, has about 2500 lines.)

You asked for ideas on "overall strategy and structure" of the code. If you decide to implement your own custom login/authentication code, it will probably go something like this:

1. Store some information in the `session` hash to identify if the user is logged in, and as which Guest/User. Make sure your sessions are stored in the DB, not in cookies.
2. Add some methods to `ApplicationController` (or a `Module` mixed in to `ApplicationController`) to encapsulate access to this login information.
3. Put a `before_filter` on all pages which require login, which redirects if the user is not logged in.
4. Add a controller which authenticates users by password OR token, and allows them to log in/out.
5. For password storage/authentication, use the `bcrypt-ruby` gem. On your User model, you'll need a `password_hash` string field and probably some methods like:

   ```
   require 'bcrypt'
   def password
     # BCrypt handles generation and storage of salts
     @password ||= ::BCrypt::Password.new(password_hash)
   end
   def password=(password)
     @password = ::BCrypt::Password.create(password)
     self.password_hash = @password
   end
   def authenticate_by_password(password)
     self.password == password
   end
   ```
6. For token-based authentication, add a `login_token` string field to your User model (or Guest or whatever it is...). Make it a unique field. You can generate the unique tokens using something like this (borrowed from Devise and modified a little):

   ```
   require 'securerandom'
   def generate_login_token
     loop do
       token = SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=lIO0', 'pqrsxyz')
       unless User.where(:login_token => token).exists?
         self.login_token = token
         self.save!
         return
       end
     end
   end
   ```
7. Then when a user hits your `login` action with `params[:token]` set, just do something like:

   ```
   if user = User.find_by_login_token(params[:token])
     # if the token is supposed to be "one time only", null out the attribute
     # log user in
   else
     # login token was invalid
   end
   ```

Make sure you put a DB index on the `login_token` field.

Is there anything else?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Alex -- I have went through [Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) previously and can understand the benefit of possibly taking this approach -- however, I'm not sure that this addresses my question of what should be the overall strategy to implement what I am trying to do and rough structure of the code involved.  Any thoughts there?

Comment: Alex - your advice is generally on how to implement custom login/authentication code, and reading through it helped me to further clarify my specific questions/issues, which I have posted.  Appreciate any additional thoughts you have.

Comment: @Adam, you can decide based on the needs of your application whether to have only a `User` model or both `User` and `Guest`. If there is only `User`, it will need to have a boolean field called `guest`. (ActiveRecord will allow you to access that field as `guest?`, which will read better.) The easiest way to keep `users` and `payments` in sync is simply to create new `Payment` and `User` records at the same place in your code (presumably there is only one such place). Or if you want, you can put an `after_create` hook on `Payment`.

Comment: You can create new "guest" users with a `nil` password. Presumably in your login page, you validate that the "password" field is not empty, so no-one will ever be able to do a password-based login for a new guest account.

Comment: Thanks, and your response gets to the heart of the matter - in using Devise, there is no `User` controller or place in my code where I create a new `User` - it is all done behind the scenes through that gem.  I was able to run some code to get access to and modify the Devise views, and am guessing it may be possible to get access to the `User` controller as well.  I'll investigate this further, as I'm guessing it has already been addressed elsewhere on stackoverflow, and report back here.  Otherwise, it sounds like I'll need to build the authentication functionality myself as you suggested.

Comment: To override Devise controllers, see [this link on Devise's wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers).  I'll use a combination of the native Devise functionality with some controller overrides to address my issues.