# Rails How to Login a Guest User with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I have this app that I'm making where users have profiles after they signup and input their information.

At the moment I'm trying to add a feature that allows for new unregistered users to go to a profile to see what the app is like before they need to sign up (I'm planning on putting a "try it for free" button on the `home_controller#index` action. For authentication, I'm using the Devise gem.

Currently, I've watched the Railscast (393) on this, but I can't figure out (after several hours of trying) how to implement guest users and log them in using Devise.

I've also read about 4 different solutions on SO, and have decided to stick to this one ([how to create a guest user in Rails 3 + Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391883/how-to-create-a-guest-user-in-rails-3-devise)):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def current_user
      super || guest_user
    end

    private

    def guest_user
     User.find(session[:guest_user_id].nil? ? session[:guest_user_id] = create_guest_user.id : session[:guest_user_id])
    end

    def create_guest_user
      u = User.create(:name => "guest", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@example.com")
      u.save(:validate => false)
      u
    end

...
end
```

I have this in my `application_controller.rb` and don't understand how I would use these functions in the home_controller#index to create a guest user and log into the profile when the "Try it" button is clicked.

I've tried manually creating a `user`, saving it without authentication and then using Devise's `sign_in` method on link like so: `<a href="<%= sign_in(:user, some_guest_user) %>">Try it!</a>` and also tried 
`<a href="<%= profile_path %>">Try it!</a>`

I tried this, but the profile throws some validation messages saying I need to log in to view it. I've also tried removing `before_filter authenticate!` on the `profiles_controller` but I can't seem to get this to work at all.

Would anyone know how to create a user on the button click, and auto sign them into a guest profile? Thanks a lot for any help, I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement this fuctionality?. I am also trying to do kind of same thing. Please share your implementation if possible.

Comment: @VieenaySiingh I implemented a variation of the chosen answer below, and added a query param `?is_guest=true` to add specific guest functionality for certain features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding on what a guest user is. You say that you want guest users to auto sign in, and that is wrong. Guest users can't sign in, because... Well, because they are guests. You want to create them, but not sign them in.

This is why you want these helper methods in your `ApplicationController`, because when you try to get the `current_user`, if that doesn't exist (`nil`), you will have a fallback (that is why you use the `||` operator), that will assign a `guest_user` as a `current_user`.

So, forget about using sign_in links for guest users and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I was really confused. So guest users do not sign in? Your explaination is great, but now I have one more question, how would one get into the user profile to try the application (because all the functionality is from within their profile) if a guest user is not the way to do so? Thanks again btw

Comment: You get the guest user to sign up , you can store the temporary data collected for the guest user using this gem rails_temporary_data and then sign them up .

Comment: I actually have a signup wizard that uses sessions right now, but this looks great! Thanks for showing me that gem, I'll try and work with it